# R - retrieve correct objects from google maps API and save to data frame

Tags: r, google-maps, twitter

for a work project I'm trying to weight bulk twitter data by geographic distribution of the tweets. Currently, I'm planning to achieve this by running the `location` information provided in most tweets I've collected through the Google Maps API and retrieving detailed information on this location as far as it's available, i.e. **town, county, state, country, longditude, latitude**.

I've adapted some R code I found on github, https://gist.github.com/josecarlosgonz/6417633, and it works pretty well, returning the desired data points into an R character vector. However, as I'll be doing this for several millions of locations, I want the data saved in a data frame which I can then match up with the tweet dataframe so as to facilitate weighting. Hence, I went ahead and modified Jose's code slightly:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(plyr)
library(RCurl)

# This is the function that transforms an "address" string into a URL readable by the G maps API

url <- function(address, return.call = "json", sensor = "false"){
  root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/"
  u <- paste(root, return.call, "?address=", address, "&sensor=", sensor, sep = "")
  return(URLencode(u))
}

# This function returns the data provided by the API
# When the request is ambiguous, e.g. "Portland", "Manchester" or "Frankfurt", it seems that the API returns the "best" match
# first, i.e. Portland, Oregon, Manchester, UK and Frankfurt am Main, Germany.
# The below set-up currently only works with U.S. localities, as the 'county' and 'state' elements are sorted at different points
# in the list for other countries. 

geoCode <- function(address,verbose=FALSE){
  if(verbose) cat(address,"\n")
  u <- url(address)
  doc <- getURL(u)
  x <- fromJSON(doc,simplify = FALSE)
  if(x$status=="OK") {
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name)){
      town <- x$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name
    } else {
    town <- NA
    }
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]]$long_name)){
      county <- x$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]]$long_name
    } else {
      county <- NA
    }
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$address_components[[3]]$long_name)){
      state <- x$results[[1]]$address_components[[3]]$long_name
    } else {
      state <- NA
    }
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$address_components[[3]]$short_name)){
      state_code <- x$results[[1]]$address_components[[3]]$short_name
    } else {
      state_code <- NA
    }
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat)){
      lat <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
    } else {
      lat <- NA
    }
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng)){
      lng <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng
    } else {
      lng <- NA
    }
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$geometry$location_type)){
      location_type <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location_type
    } else {
      location_type <- NA
    }
    if(exists(x$results[[1]]$formatted_address)){
      formatted_address <- x$results[[1]]$formatted_address
    } else {
      formatted_address <- NA
    }
    return(c(town, county, state, state_code, lat, lng, location_type, formatted_address))
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  } else {
    return(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
  }
}
```

However, when trialling this with a trivial example, I encounter several errors that I can't account for. It seems to me that, based on the level of detail provided in the string that's being fed into the G maps API, it returns different types of data at different points in the list, which is obviously bad if I want a dataset where all the counties, or long/lat data are listed in the correct columns. So, anyway, I created an arbitrary character vector with 'address' data comparable to what would be found in my tweet dataset:

```
pacific_northwest <- c('Vancouver', 'Seattle', 'Olympia', 'Redmond', 'Eugene', 'Portland', 'Tacoma', 'Whistler')
```

and then an empty data frame that google maps' output could be fed into

```
location_data.df <- data.frame(town=character(),
                           county=character(), 
                           state=character(), 
                           state_code=character(),
                           lat=character(),
                           lng=character(),
                           location_type=character(),
                           formatted_address=character(),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And finally, I wrote a simple loop that was supposed to add the output to this data.frame:

```
for (i in pacific_northwest){
  readout <- geoCode(pacific_northwest[i])
  location_data.df[nrow(location_data.df) + 1, ] <- readout
  rm(readout)
}
```

Anyway - this doesn't work, I encounter loads of errors, even with the more or less unambiguous addresses provided in `pacific_northwest`, such as: `Error in x$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]] : subscript out of bounds`

What to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.